# vb6 how to enter in debug mode while in msgbox

Tags: debugging, vb6, msgbox

I've made some searches but not found this question, sorry.

In a vb6 loop Ive a msgbox showed.
Any way to enter in debug mode (as using F8) ?
I need this in order to change the conditions of the msgbox.

And not, I can't restart the project because then I will lost the changes and the time the array took (several hours).

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are running in Debugger when the MsgBox shows, press Ctrl + Break to interrupt the MsgBox and drop into single-line stepping.

Comment: Yes, this works.
This trick was unknow for me.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

you can use breakpoints-you mark the point in code by clicking on the bar near the code and then you run the code at the moment the instruction pointer gets to this point you will see the code and the values at this point.

hope this helped.